# Create wrapper rpm for other package

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I am trying to create an RPM ("mine") to facilitate the installation of another RPM "other" (not maintained by me). This third-party RPM requires packages "foo" and "bar". I want my RPM to provide the packages "foo" and "bar" but with my own implementations. Is it possible to define a RPM that specifies that it provides the other packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so sure that I was looking for a way to alias package names that I missed the obvious 'Provides' section.

```
Provides: foo bar
```

solves the issue.

Comment: You may want to add a "`Conflicts:`" with the original package names, so it won't be installed at the same time.

Comment: Right. In my case though, the package tries to make up for the lack of these packages on the particular platform (my RPM creates symlinks and wrapper scripts to equivalent programs etc).